# Emit new style PyQt signals with arbitrary signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, python-multiprocessing, signals-slots

I am creating a PyQt GUI for an experimental setup. This will involve computationally heavy operations so I am aiming for an architecture based on the multiprocessing module and inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30048847/1291711).

The QMainWindow creates

1. child Processes with an individual "task" Queue to get instructions from the main process and a shared "callback" Queue to send back instructions to the main process
2. a QThread to poll the "callback" queue and translate the messages into signals that are connected to slots of the QMainWindow

The example uses old style signals with arbitrary signature `self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(signature), args)`. **My question is:** is it possible to replicate this functionality with new-style signals ?.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4523006/1291711) and of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11199622/1291711). However, always emitting a `valueChanged` signal with a general object does not suit my needs since I would like to connect to slots with different names depending on the signature received from one of the child Processes.

Here is a working code (note there is only one child process and one slot in the MainWindow for simplicity, but there will be several in the finished code):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class CallbackQueueToSignal(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, queue, parent=None):
        super(CallbackQueueToSignal, self).__init__(parent)
        self.queue = queue

    def _emit(self, signature, args=None):
        if args:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(signature), args)
        else:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(signature))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            signature = self.queue.get()
            self._emit(*signature)


class WorkerProcess(Process):

    def __init__(self, callback_queue, task_queue, daemon=True):
        super(WorkerProcess, self).__init__()
        self.daemon = daemon
        self.callback_queue = callback_queue
        self.task_queue = task_queue

    def _process_call(self, func_name, args=None):
        func = getattr(self, func_name)
        if args:
            func(args)
        else:
            func()

    def emit_to_mother(self, signature, args=None):
        signature = (signature, )
        if args:
            signature += (args, )
        self.callback_queue.put(signature)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            call = self.task_queue.get()
            # print("received: {}".format(call))
            self._process_call(*call)

    def text_upper(self, text):
        self.emit_to_mother('data(PyQt_PyObject)', (text.upper(),))


class MainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__(parent)

        self.data_to_child = Queue()
        self.callback_queue = Queue()

        self.callback_queue_watcher = CallbackQueueToSignal(self.callback_queue)
        self.callback_queue_watcher.start()

        self.child = WorkerProcess(self.callback_queue, self.data_to_child)
        self.child.start()

        self.browser = QtGui.QTextBrowser()
        self.lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit('Type text and press <Enter>')
        self.lineedit.selectAll()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
        self.layout_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layout_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.layout_widget)
        self.lineedit.setFocus()
        self.setWindowTitle('Upper')
        self.connect(self.lineedit, QtCore.SIGNAL('returnPressed()'), self.to_child)
        self.connect(self.callback_queue_watcher, QtCore.SIGNAL('data(PyQt_PyObject)'), self.updateUI)

    def to_child(self):
        self.data_to_child.put(("text_upper", ) + (self.lineedit.text(), ))
        self.lineedit.clear()

    def updateUI(self, text):
        text = text[0]
        self.browser.append(text)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            "Confirm Exit...",
            "Are you sure you want to exit ?",
            QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        event.ignore()

        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            # self.pipeWatcher.exit()
            self.child.terminate()
            event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    form = MainWin()
    form.show()

    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why does the connection have to depend on the signature? Just use one pre-defined signal as suggested in the questions you linked to, and send an identifier as the first parameter.

Comment: In that case, you would lose the advantage of using signals. For instance you could not connect and disconnect specific slots from a specific signal during the execution of the program. But maybe I am missing your point?

Comment: There is no way to replicate dynamically emitting custom signals with new-style signals. Custom signals must be pre-defined as class attributes. But I don't see any reason why this would affect connecting and disconnecting signals at runtime. And I also don't see how this is relevant to your actual question - your code example doesn't disconnect any signals.

Comment: @ekumoro The code does not include such connection/disconnection too keep it minimal, as mentioned in the question. Then do you mean creating several predefined signals in the `CallbackQueueToSignal`class and choosing which one to send based on the message received ? If not please clarify, maybe in an answer if you have the time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [new-style signal and slot syntax](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) requires that signals are pre-defined as class attributes on a class that inherits from `QObject`. When the class is instantiated, a bound-signal object is automatically created for the instance. The bound-signal object has `connect/disconnect/emit` methods, and a `__getitem__` syntax which allows different overloads to be selected.

Since bound-signals are *objects*, it no longer makes sense to allow the dynamic emission of arbitrary signals that was possible with the old-style syntax. This is simply because an arbitrary signal (i.e. one that is not *pre-defined*) could not have a corresponding bound-signal object for slots to connect to.

The example code in the question can still be ported to the new-style syntax, though:

```
class CallbackQueueToSignal(QtCore.QThread):
    dataSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal([], [object], [object, object])   
    ...

    def _emit(self, signal, *args):
        getattr(self, signal)[(object,) * len(args)].emit(*args)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            args = self.queue.get()
            self._emit(*args)


class WorkerProcess(Process):
    ...

    def emit_to_mother(self, *args):
        self.callback_queue.put(args)

    def text_upper(self, text):
        self.emit_to_mother('dataSignal', (text.upper(),))


class MainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...

        self.lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.to_child)
        self.callback_queue_watcher.dataSignal[object].connect(self.updateUI)
```

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. I now understand what you mean. This is a really clever way to port to the new-style syntax, thank you ! I would never have thought about overloading the signal like that.

Comment: However this is less general that the code with old-style signals since you now have to copy paste `signal_name = QtCore.pyqtSignal([], [object], [object, object])` for each different signal name you want to use. So a follow-up question would be: are there significant advantages of new-style signals that would justify the port ?

Comment: @ThibaudRuelle. I suppose the major advantage is forwards compatibility - the old-syntax is not supported at all in PyQt5. But more generally, the new-style syntax is much more pythonic and less error-prone. It's very easy to get the signature wrong with old-style syntax (especially for newbies and those unfamiliar with C++). Even worse, it fails silently. rather than raising an error like the new-style signals do. I also think it's worth saying that "readability matters": most people find the old-style syntax to be very ugly and verbose. I don't miss it at all.